# Which on is the lightest OS that can run Vmware

Tags: vmware

I am trying to use virutal machines as main systems. So I want a to run the vmware on the lightest or the least resource consuming OS, that is capable of running VMware.

Which one is it?

Comment: Any particular reason to not use any of the all-in-one VMware products?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, I would love to. if I had proper knowledge or guidance about them. Would you brief me a little bit?

Comment: Running the VMware ESXi hypervisor, as Ignacio suggested, would probably be best. If you are not sure whether your hardware is compatible, you can install and run ESXi on a USB memory stick (our main HP servers run it this way) so you don't have to commit to erasing anything already on your hard disk. Setting up and managing VMs on ESXi is very straightforward - once the server is setup, you connected to its interface using a web browser and download the management tool to install on your client PC - and that's the important thing to know, with ESXi, the server is dedicated to VMware.

Answer (score 1):

It would have to be a Linux OS running XWindows and the minimum of installed packages. You could go with mandrake , redhat or suse.

Comment: You still left me with 3 choices. Which one is the lightest?